# How to implement auto-incrementing build number in maven project?

Tags: maven, version

How to implement auto-incrementing build number in maven project?

Current version of my project is 0.9 and I'd like this from 0.9.1 to 0.9.2 and so on every build.

I've been searching for this but I couldn't get anything to work.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770364/what-is-a-good-way-to-handle-a-version-number-in-a-java-application) question,also tried maven [build number plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) and I've tried this [blog](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/10/how-to-automate-project-versioning-and-release-with-maven/), but nothing seems to work.

I tried the maven version plugin but it changes the jar name to app-0.9.[commit_hashcode].jar but I don't want this.

I want the jar name to be app-0.9.jar and I want to access the build number from a properties file or something.

Comment: every build or release?

Comment: yes. increment on every build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [build number plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin) you referenced does support incremental numeric versions based on a properties file (in addition to versions based on SCM and timestamp). The default is to use SCM hash so you have to tell it to use an incremental number.

```
<configuration>
    <format>{0,number,integer}</format>
    <items>
        <item>buildNumber</item>
    </items>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How about a full example?